# MySQL - AWS RDS - Replication node is stopped

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I have a replication node on RDS that when shown on AWS Console it states that there's an error on RDS replication node (ERROR) and it has stopped replicating. What can I do to restart the replica?

- When tried to [restart manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-stored-proc-replicating.html#mysql_rds_start_replication)

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
ERROR 1872 (HY000): Slave failed to initialize relay log info structure from the repository
```

- When inspecting the SLAVE STATUS

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: [HIDDEN]
                  Master_User: [HIDDEN]
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.275700
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 157
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.023273
                Relay_Log_Pos: 886423
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.275700
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 13124
                   Last_Error: Slave failed to initialize relay log info structure from the repository
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 886301
              Relay_Log_Space: 0
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 13124
               Last_SQL_Error: Slave failed to initialize relay log info structure from the repository
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID: [HIDDEN]
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 230909 16:19:12
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.09 sec)
```

- When inspecting the master node `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File                       | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin-changelog.276745 | 11298904 |              |                  |                   |
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have parallel replication enabled? If you test it disabling (settign it to 0) and resume replication